# debug express js application visual studio code:

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug my express js application through visual studio code 
here is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 9229
        }
    ],
    "compounds": []
}
```

And my application is running in port 3000 but when i run debugger i got the following error

> Debugging with legacy protocol because Node.js version could not be
>   determined (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229)

Answer (score 1):

You can change request as launch,add protocol as inspector in your file and put your main server file in program, here my server file called as server.js.

```
 {
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
      {
         "type": "node",
         "request": "launch",
         "name": "Launch Program",
         "protocol": "inspector",
         "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: this gave me antoher error `Ensure Node was launched with --inspect` and is started my app with `nodemon --inspect ` but still the same error

Comment: can you update your question with your project structure? what is your name of node main server file?

Comment: project created with express-generator  and main file is `bin/www` in the root folder

Comment: what is your name of the main server file?

Comment: as i told its  `bin/www` www is the main file, i tried with this `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/www",` but still the same error

Comment: What version of node are you using?